# Google Apps Script code is out of sync with latest deployment

Tags: google-apps-script

I've somehow managed to end up with an older version of the code.gs and index.html files in my project than what is currently deployed.  Looking at the history of the project, I can see where an older version of the code replaced what I was working on.

My question is whether or not it's possible to reverse the code out of a deployment, or is it a one  way trip, and i'll have to recreate all of the code?

I've tried using the Project History to look back at versions of the code.

Comment: It seems that it can be achieved with the script editor in the near future. https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/08/apps-script-project-history.html